# How to use Cells with Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have a String value in `A1`.

Why is it that if I run the following code it captures the value correctly:

```
arrInputData(1, 1) = Worksheets("inputData").Range("A1")
```

However, a slight change to it

```
arrInputData(1, 1) = Worksheets("inputData").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1))
```

throws the following error:

> Runtime error 1004. Application defined or object defined error

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrInputData(1, 1) = Worksheets("inputData").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1))`

is a shorter way of writing:

`arrInputData(1, 1) = Worksheets("inputData").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1))`

and will cause an error if "inputData" is not the active sheet